# How do you draw a random irregular polygon in java? (Asteroids)

Tags: java, mathematics, graphics, swing

I am coding an Asteroids game in Java. In the real arcade game, asteroids are made of irregular shapes like this: [image]

When I code, I can only set asteroids to 1 or another specific shape, like this:

[image]

I want to make all of the asteroids in my game of totally randomly generated shapes, and I am already tired of designing specific shapes of my own. Here is a snippet of my code that generates the asteroid's shape. P.S: The image does not show it, but I am using the `Polygon` class and constructor which only enables me to input 2 int[]s and a number of sides.

```
   public void makeShape() {
    int x = (int) this.x;
    int y = (int) this.y;
    this.shape = new Polygon(new int[]{x - 15, x - 30, x - 10, x - 13, x,x + 10, x + 10}, new int[]{y - 30, y - 15, y + 5, y + 30, y + 35, y + 30, y}, 7); 
}
```

I have tried putting all of the variables on `Math.random()`, but it outputs nothing but a scribble, even if I were using the `Polygon` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could let a point travel on a circle in discreet steps and adjust the radius for each step, that would make it look jagged and irregular.

Something like this might work for you:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param px The center X of the shape
 * @param py The center Y of the shape
 * @param numberOfNodes How many dents the shape can have. 
 * @param minRadius Radius of the deepest valley
 * @param maxRadius Radius of the tallest mountain
 * @return Some shape
 */
private Polygon makeShape(int px, int py, int numberOfNodes, double minRadius, double maxRadius) {
    // Split a full circle into numberOfNodes step, this is how much to advance each part
    double angleStep = Math.PI * 2 / numberOfNodes;
    Polygon shape = new Polygon();
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfNodes; ++i) {
        double targetAngle = angleStep * i; // This is the angle we want if all parts are equally spaced
        double angle = targetAngle + (rnd.nextDouble() - 0.5) * angleStep * 0.25; // add a random factor to the angle, which is +- 25% of the angle step
        double radius = minRadius + rnd.nextDouble() * (maxRadius - minRadius); // make the radius random but within minRadius to maxRadius
        // calculate x and y positions of the part point
        double x = Math.cos(angle) * radius; 
        double y = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
        shape.addPoint((int)x, (int)y);
    }
    shape.translate(px, py);
    return shape;
}
```

`px` and `py` correspond to your `this.x` and `this.y`